# Actionscript 3: Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to test and write if the microphone access was allowed or not in ActionScript 3 but now, ever if there is no compilation error, it doesn't ask me the microphone access, nothings happens when I launch the SWF file.

This is my code :

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;
import flash.media.Microphone;


var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

if(mic){
    mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus);
}

else{
    trace("No micro");
}

function onMicStatus(event: StatusEvent): void {
    if (event.code == "Microphone.Unmuted") {
        trace("Microphone access was allowed.");

    } else if (event.code == "Microphone.Muted") {
    trace("Microphone access was denied.");
    }
}
```

Comment: use the debugger to get the actual line number, that's helpful.    You should also be importing `StatusEvent`, not just `Microphone` (that is likely the issue).   `import flash.events.StatusEvent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from this line :

```
mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus);
```

because [`Microphone.getMicrophone()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#getMicrophone()) can return `null` :

> If Microphone.getMicrophone() returns null, either the microphone is in use by another application, or there are no microphones installed on the system. To determine whether any microphones are installed, use Microphone.names.length (Microphone without "s", there is an error on Adobe's doc).

So to avoid that error, you can use a simple `if` statement :

```
if(mic){
    mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus);
}
```

You can also use `Microphone.names.length` to verify if you have an Microphone installed (at least one) before creating a `Microphone` object :

```
if(Microphone.names.length > 0){
    var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus);
}
```

**Edit :**

> To display the Flash Player Microphone Settings panel, which lets the user choose the microphone to be referenced by Microphone.getMicrophone, use Security.showSettings().

To display the Flash Player Microphone Settings panel, you can use :

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.MICROPHONE);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Ok. I edited my code. Now there is no error but it doesn't ask me for the microphone.

Comment: @MatR For that you can use `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.MICROPHONE);`, answer edited.